# Facing issue while running loop controller with mulitple threads

Tags: rest, automation, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Below is my scenario
1.login - from the response of login I will get one id
2.save answer - a user has to give 16 answers for that I am using loop controller + id which I am getting from login sampler
3. Submit - I need to submit the call if I am getting success on all 16 answers + I have to use response login id
What is the best way to do it in JMeter please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Given you have [`rest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest) in your tags I believe the server responds with a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) so you can save the `id` from the server into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) which allows executing arbitrary [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries to get "interesting" attributes values from JSON.

With regards to sending the requests, most probably you will need to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type), it can be done via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Comment: I did the same but when I run 100 concurrent users then 16 loop call are not going coz other threads changing the value of ID in meter variable due to which my scenario is not completing.

Comment: This is not possible, [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are [local](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html) to each JMeter thread (virtual user). If you're using a JMeter Property to store the ID - make sure to add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function to it so each virtual user could have its own ID. See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%e2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/) article for more details